# Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: users is not mapped [Select username from users]

Tags: java, rest

What is causing the error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: users is not mapped [Select username from users].

I am trying to validate users when they try to login and it is my first time creating a web API. Is this error caused because I am not properly querying the database's data? Or is my overall syntax not correct?

Here is my `UserRepository`:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query("Select username from users")
    User findByUsername(@Param("username") String username);
}
```

and here is my `LoginController`:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    ServletRequest servletRequest;

    @Autowired
    ServletResponse response;

    @GetMapping("/signin")
    public void login(@RequestBody User user) throws IOException {
        User storedUser = userService.getUsername(user.getUsername());
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

        if (storedUser == null) {
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, 
                    "The username or password you have entered is invalid.");
        }
        else if (storedUser.getPassword() == user.getPassword()) {
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED, "valid.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide some more informartions about the `User` entity and the `UserService`.

Comment: This can't be marked at solved in the system here unless you submit your solution as an answer rather than as an edit to the question.  I reverted your edit. Instead please use box below this to answer your own question.  You will need to summarize the process rather than providing a link to the solution.  Without that, your question and answer won't be useful to others with similar problems in the future if the link stops working.

Comment: By default, Query uses JPQL language(build query based on entities objects), but It seems you are using native SQL in your query. You need to specify native flag for your query. Example `@Query(value = "Select username from users", nativeQuery = true)`